# Get X value from stacked series barchat on typescript - amCharts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, amcharts

I need to retrieve the value of the XAxis on typescript

[image]

Actually I tried using `adapter` in this way, but `value` is filled with `{valueX}`

```
this.series.adapter.add( 'tooltipText', (value:any , target) => {
  var ticks: number = (value) as number;
  return value; //this return {valueX}
});
```

I need the exact value that is showing on chart (for example 34,590,000,000), not the tooltipText template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in this way

```
this.series.adapter.add( 'tooltipText', (text: string, target) => {
  var value = target.tooltipDataItem.values.valueX.value;
  return value;
});
```